# How to prevent browser opening new window if it dosent understand the address

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm using custom protocol to open a windows appliction from my web application it working correctly without any problem but if the windows application is not insatlled in pc it opens a new window and showing The address wasn't understood . I want to prevent this and need to show a message my current code is given below

```
var url="test:?var="+value+"?var2="+value2+"?var3="+value3;
var win= window.open(url, 'test', 'width=1000,height=700,top=1,left=1,resizable=yes', '1');
if(win==null || win.closed==true)
   alert("Please install the application ");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I found a solution [here](http://www.rajeshsegu.com/2012/09/browser-detect-custom-protocols/comment-page-1/) its not bulletproof but it will save the day

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this..

Check what will be the value of `url` when the windows app is not installed.If it is null,we can check ..

```
if(url==null || win.closed==true)
   alert("Please install the application ");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax for that . First send an ajax request to check if the url exist . If does not satisfy open the window else give error .

```
function checkUrlstatus (yoururl){
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest;
    request.open('GET', yoururl, true);
    request.send();
    request.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(request.readyState==4){
            console.log(request.readyState);
            // code for opening the url
            return true;
        }else{
            // code for error message on the same page
            return false;
        }
    }
};
```